# Liquid level sensor

Tags: sensors

We're currently working on a direct sketch to printed circuit board printer for our design project. We need a sensor for the ink level since we're using a pen. Can we use this ( https://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Non-contact_Liquid_Level_Sensor_XKC-Y25-T12V_SKU:_SEN0204) as a sensor even if its non-conductive type ink (normal ink we use for writing)? Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Your link page says:

> There are no special requirements for the liquid

So, I would not concern about the conductivity of the liquid.